# Possible to add code tag button in MediaWiki editor?

Tags: mediawiki

In the MediaWiki editor are there buttons for bold, italic and other styling, but not one for adding the `<code> ... </code>` tags around the selected text.

Can such a button be added to the editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your wiki has the [WikiEditor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWikiEditor) extension installed (installed by default).

This extension allows you to customize the toolbar. They have a full guide over at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiEditor/Toolbar_customization